# React component renders twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prismic.io

I have text from my Prismic CMS, where I want to apply 'dynamic words' on.
Dynamic words are words from the CMS, that have an image linked to it, so if a text contains a dynamic word, it changes it to a span with data attributes, so an underline appears under each dynamic word, and if you click on it, the right image shows up.

In my code, I get the innerHTML of the text block, with the prismic render and all the tags inside of it, and then I want to change the innerHTML, to apply the dynamic words to the text and then change the innerHTML of the text block to the html with the dynamic words.

But I have a few issues, my React component renders twice, so when it renders the first time and I console log `newText`, it is the right one. But on the second render it also changes the data attributes of the dynamic word span's, so the whole html is getting screwed up.

Does anyone know why it would run twice, or maybe has a better solution to fix my problem?

```
export const ArticleBodyText = ({ text, dynamic_words }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const textblocks = document.querySelectorAll('#textblock p');
    textblocks.forEach(item => {
      const textblock = item.innerHTML;
      const newText = setDynamicWords(textblock, dynamic_words);
      console.log(newText);
      item.innerHTML = newText;
    });
  }, [dynamic_words]);

  return (
    <TextBlock id="textblock">
      <RichText render={text} />
    </TextBlock>
  );
};
```

Comment: It probaly runs twice, because your `dynamic_words` changes over time. E.g. first it is undefined because it is not loaded yet and then it is loaded. If that is the case, just check for `if (dynamic_words != null) ...` in your useEffect hook.

Comment: May be because you have <React.StrictMode/> ? See this -https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

Comment: Try to use refs instead of using document query selectors in react

Comment: I btw don't use <React.StrictMode/>

Comment: Where does the "setDynamicWords" defined? Is it changing the "dynamic_words" object?

Comment: If the component renders twice even without useEffect, you need to share the component which actually renders this one, apparently that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

search for a hook called useeffect once

> https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-useeffect-only-once/

Answer (score 0):

Just make a state that returns if true, so after the second render, nothing will happen.

```
export const ArticleBodyText = ({ text, dynamic_words }) => {
const [hasUpdated, setHasUpdated] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasUpdated) return;
    setHasUpdated(true);
    const textblocks = document.querySelectorAll('#textblock p');
    textblocks.forEach(item => {
      const textblock = item.innerHTML;
      const newText = setDynamicWords(textblock, dynamic_words);
      console.log(newText);
      item.innerHTML = newText;
    });
  }, [dynamic_words]);

  return (
    <TextBlock id="textblock">
      <RichText render={text} />
    </TextBlock>
  );
};
```

Comment: Not working, still rendering twice

Answer (score 0):

Remove React.StrictMode from ReactDOM.render code

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
<App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <>
<App />
  </>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```